# How to find entry point in .exe?

Tags: ida

Kind of a simple question. How does a program like IDA locate the entry point of an exe? If I wanted to, could i find this with just a hex editor manually?

Comment: Pe format (portable exectable)is documented exes are created in pe format. The header of pe contains a structure member called Address of Entrypoint

Answer (score 7):

The entry point is defined in the PE header. The full docs for its layout can be found here [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10))

The field is `DWORD AddressOfEntryPoint`. So you would have to work out the offset of this value from the start of the header based on the size of the preceding fields to find it in a hex editor